# Finding the current URL or "main" controller from within a Turbo Frame in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, hotwire-rails, turbo-frames

I have a Turbo Frame on my page which uses the `src` attribute to load in `/chats/`. Within this frame I want to be able to know whether the **main** page is using the `show` action of the `groups` controller, i.e. the URL of the page is at `/groups/group_name`.

Using `current_page?(controller: 'groups', action: 'show')` returns false as it sees itself as in the `chats` controller. How do I work around this?

Comment: I've never needed to try this, but can you add query parameters to the `src` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the options I've found:

1. `request.referrer`

There doesn't appear to be a built-in way of getting to the controller class / action in the way that you're describing, but you can access the URL of the page which initiated the Turbo request (groups_controller#show) through `request.referrer`. This will be the fully-qualified URL for the page, such as `http://localhost:3000/groups/1/show`.

2. use query parameters

This requires changes to view code (you must add query params to all links where you need this functionality), but it allows you to pass controller/action names and any other arbitrary data you'd like.

Example:

in application_controller.rb:

```
# define a method to capture the information you wish to access during your Turbo stream request
def current_route_info
  {
    path: current_path,
    controller: params[:controller],
    action: params[:action]
  }
end
```

No need to touch the groups controller in this example.

in show.html.erb (the page which submits the Turbo request)

```
<%= form_with url: turbo_view_path(info: current_route_info) do %>
...
<% end %>
OR
<%= link_to turbo_view_path(info: current_route_info) do %>
...
<% end %>
OR
<!-- you could also manually build the URL & encode the query params if you need to avoid URL helpers-->
<turbo-frame id="" src=chats_partial_path(info: current_route_info)>
...
<turbo-frame>
```

chats partial controller (which handles the Turbo request)

```
def turbo_view_method
  params[:info]
  # => info as defined in current_route_info
end
```

3. use `flash`

I've just learned the many ways you can use `flash` for this type of functionality that extends across requests. This is less work than using query parameters, mainly because you don't need to adjust your view code.

Example:

groups controller (which renders the show view, which submits the Turbo requests)

```
def show
  # stick the current controller and action params into flash
  # again, you can add any other arbitrary (primitive) data you'd like
  flash[:referrer] = params.slice(:controller, :action)
  ...
  ...
end
```

chats partial controller (which handles the Turbo requests)

```
def chats_turbo_method
  flash[:referrer]
  # => { controller: "some_controller", action: "show" }
  # NOTE: flash will retain this :referrer key for exactly 1 further request.
  # If you require this info for multiple Turbo requests,
  # you must add:
  flash.keep(:referrer)
  # and you will have access to flash[:referrer] for as many Turbo requests as you want to make from group#show
end
```